# Remove symbol element from SVG using DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, svg

I have the following svg file, as you can see the paths are wrapped in a `<symbol>`, **I would like the symbol tag to removed, and the contents moved up into the svg**, so getting rid of that surrounding  tag basically.

```xml
<svg width="48" height="48" fill="none" stroke="ff4444" stroke-width="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol stroke="red" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="accessibility">
        <path d="M2 16L2.8 14M6 16L5.2 14M5.2 14L4 11L2.8 14M5.2 14H2.8"/>
        <path d="M20 13L22 10M20 13L18 10M20 13L20 16"/>
        <path d="M8 12L10 10V16"/>
        <path d="M13 12L15 10V16"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

#### What I've tried

```php
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->load('path/to/file.svg');

$symbolNode = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('symbol')[0];

foreach($symbolNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $domDocument->appendChild($childNode);
}

echo $domDocument->saveXML();
```

But that is just returning the full contents of my svg file again, without any change.
Is there a good way to go about this?